# VB.NET - Count the distinct variables in the list of collection

Tags: vb.net

I have this scenario where I have a variable = list of collection below, and I need to count uniquely the value of ITEM in fileRecords:

```
      Dim fileRecords as List(Of FileRec)

      Public Class FileRec
           Public Property ID as Integer
           Public Property TagNo as String
           Public Property Item as String
      End Class
```

[image]

As you can see, the fileRecords have 3 rows, the ITEM variable have two distinct values, I need to count how many distinct values there are in the ITEM variable inside the fileRecords.

Hoping someone could guide me how to solve this. I tried to google, but it's not helping me much.

I should have an answer of fish = 2, chicken = 1.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `TagNo` isn't a string? You can't store values like "a1" in an Integer property.

Comment: You really must turn the `Option Strict` **On**. You should not assign `String` values to a property (`TagNo`) of type `Integer`. You need first to fix that then [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) the `TagNo` to get the count of each distinct item.

Comment: Ow sorry, yup it should be string

Answer (score 1):

> I should have an answer of fish = 2, chicken = 1.

This is will do the rough work:

```
Dim result = fileRecords.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Item)
```

And then print results like this:

```
For Each r In result
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Key} = {r.Count()}")
Next
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/IeLtgz

Or you could combine those into a single string:

```
Dim result As String = string.Join(", ",
         fileRecords.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Item).
             Select(Function(g) $"{g.Key} = {g.Count()}") 
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want,

```
    Dim fileRecords As New List(Of FileRec)
    ' sample data
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "gator"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "fish"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "chicken"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "chicken"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "fish"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "chicken"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "gator"})
    fileRecords.Add(New FileRec With {.Item = "fish"})

    Dim itemCounts = From fr In fileRecords
                         Group By item = fr.Item
                         Into itemCTS = Group, Count()
                         Order By item

    For Each i In itemCounts
        Debug.WriteLine("{0,-10}   {1}", i.item, i.Count)
    Next
```

Results

```
chicken      3
fish         3
gator        2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Count_fish= herefileRecords.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Item = "fish").Count

Dim Count_chicken= herefileRecords.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Item = "chicken").Count
```

or use

```
   For Each rw In fileRecords.AsEnumerable
     MessageBox.Show(fileRecords.Where(Function(x) x.Item = rw.Item).Count)
   Next
```

Comment: `Dim Count_fish = herefileRecords.Count(Function(x) x.Item = "fish")`

Comment: Not tenable if there are hundreds of items.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncomfortable with using Linq, it is very easy to roll your own solution:

```
Dim Result As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim items As New HashSet(Of String)

For Each fR In fileRecords
    If items.Add(fR.Item) Then
        Result.Add(fR.Item, 1)
    Else
        Result(fR.Item) += 1
    End If
Next

For Each kP In Result
    Console.WriteLine(kP.Key + ": " + kP.Value.ToString)
Next
```

A HashSet is a convenient way to find unique entries.  Its Add method returns true, if the item was successfully added (i.e. the value did not exist already), and false if the item already existed.  If we get a true, we add a new value to the Dictionary holding the results; if not, we know that the Dictionary already contains this item, so we simply increment the count.